# Flask + SSE : why is time.sleep() required?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, server-sent-events, python-multiprocessing

I'm building a flask app that will have a background processs (with `multiprocessing.Process`) polling a web service for new data, queueing the data so that a Server-Sent-Events endpoint can stream it to the client.

The sample code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools
import time
from flask import Flask, Response, redirect, request, url_for

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    for i, c in enumerate(itertools.cycle('ABCDEFG')):
        time.sleep(1) 
        q.put( c )


app = Flask(__name__)

q = Queue()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.headers.get('accept') == 'text/event-stream':
        def events():
            for i, c in enumerate(itertools.cycle('ABCDEFG')):
                #yield "data: %s \n\n" % (q.get())
                yield "data: %s \n\n" % (c)
                time.sleep(0.01)
        return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='index.html'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True, port=23423)

    p.join()
```

The problem is that in Chrome, if I remove the `time.delay(0.01)` after the `yield`, the SSE seems to hang (client side).

Comment: Why not use a package like [Flask-SSE](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-sse) for handling server-sent events?

Answer (score 2):

The time.sleep is required so your client doesn't get overwhelmed with messages. Otherwise, the Python loop will run continuously sending messages as fast as it can loop. As you have it set up now, the client will receive approximately 100 messages per second (minus a few for processing time).